# Split JSON data and only get the variables names

Tags: php, json, forms, http-post

I am making an CMS, Where you have to put in your own JSON data string. 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceX63.png)

Then its going to a php file. But in that file I want to split the data string

from something like this:

```
 {"main_object": {"audio":"nl", "title":"Opdracht 1", "vraag":"[0, 1, "a"]", "antwoord"["yes", "no", 0]" }}
```

to this

```
["audio", "title", "vraag", "antwoord"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following PHP code:

```
 <?php
 $JSONData = '{"main_object": {"audio":"nl", "title":"Opdracht 1", "vraag":"[0, 1, "a"]", "antwoord"["yes", "no", 0]" }}'; //In reality you'll be getting the JSON data from the form rather than assigning it here.

  $arrayData = json_decode($JSONData, true);
  if ($arrayData !== null 
      && is_array($arrayData)
      && isset($arrayData["main_object"])
      && is_array($arrayData["main_object"])) { //JSON was valid and in the correct format
      $usableData = array_keys($arrayData["main_object"]);
      //Do whatever you need to do with your $usableData
  } else {
     //Handle badly formatted data here.
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using json_decode, care, your JSON string is not correct :

```
$json_string = '{"main_object": {"audio":"nl", "title":"Opdracht 1", "vraag":[0, 1, "a"], "antwoord":["yes", "no", 0]}}';

// Add TRUE to force an array, not an object
$array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
print_r(array_keys($array['main_object']));
```

It works with this code. I tried.

Comment: If I do that I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' "

Comment: Yep, I forgot a semicolon. Try with my new code. Your JSON is not well formated by the way.